# Array formula and MAX value of 2 cells

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to get max value between 2 cells (one is same column, previous row, another is in the same row, but different column) with an array formula. I use array, because I need it to be updated automatically row after row with each new entry in column A without adding formula to new cells each time.
Just MAX formula is following:

```
I3512=MAX(I3511,C3512)
```

This array formula gives same result in each following cell

```
I3513 = ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A3513:A),,MAX(I3512,C3513)))
```

This formula also, gives me the same result in each row, as counting the max from C column.

```
I3513 = ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A3513:A),,MAX(I3512:I,C3513:C)))
```

Also I tried this version, but it fails in the middle, showing wrong values.

```
I3513 = ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A3513:A),,if(I3512:I<C3513:C,C3513:C, I3512:I)))
```

How to apply MAX formula to all rows in column **I** after row 3513, finding between previous cell and another column same row.

[Suggested formula result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIi4P.png)

Comment: Can you post a sheet with some sample data and desired result as I am not sure I understand exactly what you want.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s2aRw-wxBUo3S9g9Dih2rjCqCs7gwSdKZiCpIYdgXKo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In your screenshot of the suggested formula result, it shows row 3513, but your sample document only goes to row ~60. The screenshot also does not show the values that the suggested result should reference.

Comment: I created the example document, but it doesn't contain all 9000 rows. Let's imagine, that I need to calculate I2=MAX(I1,C2), then I3=MAX(I2,C3) and so on. But I need it be updated and shown automatically, when I import new rows after 60. And have no need to extend the formula by hand. That is why I want to use ArrayFormula. Or probably other options are available.

Answer (score 0):

if just two columns use `IF` in row 3513:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3513:A="";; IF({I3512:I; ""}>C3513:C; {I3512:I; ""}; C3513:C)))
```

Comment: It is what we tried already 
I3513 = ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A3513:A),,if(I3512:I<C3513:C,C3513:C, I3512:I)))
Unfortunately, it is not working properly. Values are incorrect

Comment: What actually is displayed
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIi4P.png

Comment: @InnaIvaniuk can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s2aRw-wxBUo3S9g9Dih2rjCqCs7gwSdKZiCpIYdgXKo/edit?usp=sharing

Highlighted with Blue is import from different second sheet.
Highlighted with Orange is where arrayformula works correctly.
Highlighted with Green is where I want arrayformula to be used (or any other possibility to autofill the formulas till the end, when new rows will be added).

Comment: see the red cell: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s2aRw-wxBUo3S9g9Dih2rjCqCs7gwSdKZiCpIYdgXKo/edit#gid=618810427

Comment: It is not working correctly. At I46 it shows different result from what should be. I column always should be the biggest number from all previous. In order to recalculate, following values should be deleted one by one.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [`OFFSET`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en&ref_topic=3105472)

For example:

```
C3 =
{
    "MAX PNL";
    "N/A";
    ArrayFormula(
        IF(
            OFFSET(A3:A1000, -1, 0) > B3:B1000,
            OFFSET(A3:A1000, -1, 0),
            B3:B1000
        )
    )
}
```

[image]

Bear in mind with this technique you can't use ranges like `A3:A` as this will give you an error:

[image]

This is because since it references two rows, it gets confused and always requires more rows.

Comment: Thank you.But it doesn't work as formula should be following:
B2 =
{
    "MAX PNL";
    "N/A";
    ArrayFormula(
        IF(
            OFFSET(A2:A1000, -1, 0) > B1:B999,
            OFFSET(A2:A1000, -1, 0),
            B1:B999
        )
    )
}

Comment: Now it overwrites itself and gives wrong numbers.

Comment: Your change that you mention in the comments wont work. The OFFSET is what makes it go to the previous row not making the range different.. So your example of `I2=MAX(I1,C2)  I3=MAX(I2,C3)` in my example is `C2=MAX(A1,B2)  C3=MAX(A2,B3)`  - i'm not sure why you say it doesn't work.